# "Iterating" through methods

Tags: java, methods, call, method-call

Let's say I've got a Java object that's got among others the following methods:

```
public String getField1();
public String getField2();
public String getField3();
public String getField4();
public String getField5();
```

Is there a way to iterate through these methods and call 'em like the following code?

```
String fields = "";
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i ++){
   fields += object.(getField+i) + " | ";
}
```

Thank you for your upcoming ideas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a way using reflection:

```
try{
  Method m= object.getClass().getMethod("getField"+String.valueOf(i), new Class[]{});
  fields+=(String)m.invoke(object);
}catch(...){...}
```

**However:**
This business all smells of bad coding practice!
Can't you rewrite all the `getFieldN()` methods like this?

```
String getField(int fieldNum)
```

You are asking for trouble by creating numbered methods. Remember that reflection is slow and should only be used when String-based method calls are absolutely essential to the flow of your program. I sometimes use this technique for user-defined scripting languages where you have to get a method **by name**. That isn't the case at all here, your calls are **integer-indexed**. You should therefore keep the integer as a parameter.

If this is legacy code and you are absolutely unable to change this bad coding, then you might be better off creating a new method `getMethod(int)` as above to wrap the existing methods, that just delegates to the numbered `getMethodN()` methods.

Answer (score 17):

```
Class yourClass = YourClass.class;
for (Method method : yourClass.getMethods()){
    method.invoke(obj, args);           
}
```

See [this guide](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) for reference.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention, that my class has other methods too that I don't want to invoke. Would your code still do the job then?

Comment: If you know their signatures you could call only them basing on `method.getName()` and on `method.getParameterTypes()`

Answer (score 0):

To be able to select specific fields and order you should specifiy them i.e. by a list of field names.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class CsvReflect {
    int a = 10;
    String b = "test";
    Date d = new Date();

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public Date getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public static String toCsv(Object obj, String fields, String separator) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fields,",");
        while ( st.hasMoreElements() ) {
            String field = st.nextToken();
            Method getter = obj.getClass().getMethod("get"+ field, new Class[]{});
            String val = "" + getter.invoke(obj, new Class[]{});
            sb.append( val );
            if ( st.hasMoreElements() ) {
                sb.append(separator);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        CsvReflect csv  = new CsvReflect();
        System.out.println( csv.toCsv( csv ,"A,B,D", "|" ));
    }
}
```